# How is the Msg Object Created?

Tags: solidity

I checked the documentation about the msg object, but I could not find any explanation about how the msg is created. My interest is to understand the scope of msg and also if that object could be corrupted by a hacker (eg by changing msg.sender).

Has anyone any details about how msg is created in Ethereum?

Comment: We could override msg in the context of a contract, since it is like a global object That's one thing to look out for in other contracts

Comment: Is there a document describing how msg is created?